# Paginated links on items generated using a custom search module does not work

Tags: component, development, fix-my-code, jroute

I am trying to build a component called com_usedbooks with a module called mod_usedsearch. The user can view books by clicking a Menu Item called 'Used Books' (/used-books) which will show a paginated list or by searching it using a module from any page where they can filter it by author and author.

I got the List View working but when I search with the module, I have two problems which I think are interrelated:

When the search form in the module is submitted, it seems to be getting submitted to current component context. So if I am submitting the Search Form from the root URL, I get a different query string (`/?genre=fiction&author=all&option=com_usedbooks&view=search&Itemid=101`) compared to when I submit the Search Form in the Used Books List page (`/used-books?genre=fiction&author=all&option=com_usedbooks&view=search&Itemid=108`).

In both cases, the list page with the correct filtered data is displayed but with one catch and that is when I click on Page 2 on the pagination links, it goes to: `/used-books/fiction/0?author=all&start=5`.

My guess is that the problem lies in the router but I am struggling to find what it is. What I am trying to do is when the search form is submitted from any component context, it will be have a query string like `/used-books/search/?genre=fiction&author=all` and similarly for the pagination to be `/used-books/search/?genre=fiction&author=all&limit=5` and so on.

I am not sure what I would put on the case 'search' to achieve what I want.

I have referenced the relevant bits of code below:

```
<!-- Module Search Form -->
<form name="books-search" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php')?>" method="get">
<!-- fields -->
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_usedbooks">
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="search">


<?php
/* Model
 * /com_usedbooks/models/search.php 
*/

class UsedbooksModelSearch extends JModelList {

    protected function getListQuery() {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Get the genre
        $genre = $this->getState('genre', '');

        $query
            ->select('*')
            ->from($db->quoteName('used_books'))
            ->where('genre = ' . $db->quote($genre))
            ->order('id ASC');

        return $query;
    }

    protected function populateState ($ordering = null, $direction = null) {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        $this->setState('genre', $app->input->get('genre', '', 'STRING'));

        // Limit the number of list items per page
        $this->setState('list.limit', $app->input->get('limit', 5, 'uint'));

        /* Sets the offset where the page should start, for e.g
         * Page limitstart=5 will start the list with the 6th item
        */
        $this->setState('list.start', $app->input->get('limitstart', 0, 'uint'));
    }
}

/* View
 * /com_usedbooks/views/search/tmpl/default.php 
*/
class UsedbooksViewSearch extends JViewLegacy
{
    // Overwriting JView display method
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        // Get the Used Books Array
        $this->items = $this->get('Items');

        // Pagination
        $this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');

        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
?>

<!-- /com_usedbooks/views/search/tmpl/default.php -->
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(JFactory::getURI()->toString()); ?>" method="get">
    <?php foreach ($usedBooks as $usedBook): ?>
        <h2><?php echo $usedBook->title . ' - '. $usedBook->author; ?></h2> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->getLimitBox(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->getResultsCounter(); ?>
</form>

<?php
/* Router
 * /com_usedbooks/router.php 
*/
function UsedbooksBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();

    if(isset($query['genre'])){
        $segments[] = $query['genre'];
        unset($query['genre']);
    }

    if(isset($query['author'])){
        $segments[] = $query['author'];
        unset($query['author']);
    }

    if(isset($query['id'])){
        $segments[] = $query['id'];
        unset($query['id']);
    }
    unset( $query['view'] );

    return $segments;
}

function UsedbooksParseRoute($segments)
{
    $vars = array();
    $app =& JFactory::getApplication();
    $menu =& $app->getMenu();
    $item =& $menu->getActive();

    // Count segments
    $count = count($segments);

    //Handle View and Identifier
    switch($item->query['view'])
    {
    case 'usedbooks':
        if($count == 1) {
            $vars['view'] = 'genre';
        }
        if($count == 2) {
            $vars['view'] = 'author';
        }
        if($count == 3) {
            $vars['view'] = 'usedbook';
        }
        $id = explode( ':', $segments[$count-1] );
        $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];

        break;

    case 'genre':
        if($count == 1) {
            $vars['view'] = 'genre';
        }
        if($count == 2) {
            $vars['view'] = 'author';
        }
        $id = explode(':', $segments[$count-1]);
        $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
        break;

    case 'author':
        if($count == 1) {
            $vars['view'] = 'author';
        }
        if($count == 2) {
            $vars['view'] = 'usedbook';
        }
        $id = explode(':', $segments[$count-1]);
        $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
        break;

    case 'usedbook':
        $reg = explode(':', $segments[$count-1]);
        $vars['reg'] = (int) $reg[0];
        $vars['view'] = 'usedbook';
        break;

    case 'search':

        break;
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

Comment: Did you add your start and length pagination URL params to your component level controller's $safeurlparams  variable before calling parent class display method?  Also, did you add the existing filters (author, genre) which built the result set; into the search results form so when pagination request fires they're available to the model?

Comment: Hi Brian, not sure if I 'understood' your questions correctly as I am just starting to learn the workings of Joomla's MVC in the component but let me try.

Comment: Pressed enter by mistake, and had not idea could edit for only 5 minutes. Here is the remaining part of the reply:

1. I have set the start/length pagination URL params (limitstart and start on the two models (/models/search.php and /models/usedcars.php) in populateState method. 

2. And the existing filters are available to the model as I have used the following code on the action:

`<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(JFactory::getURI()->toString()); ?>" method="get">`

Comment: Saw one item which will resolve the two different urls at least, you wouldn't happen to have a Dev site where I could see live the pagination issues.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see the issue with the search module form destination url.   The form action attribute needs the option and view parameters.  I see you added them as hidden field at the end of the form,  but try removing those fields and adding to the JRoute url like so:

```
<form name="books-search" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_usedbooks&view=search')?>" method="get">
```

Since these are crucial for the frame work properly routing the request, this should at least ensure the module form routes to the proper component and view.

Comment: Ha I was writing a reply to say I have solved the issue (with a lot of help from hple in the Joomla IRC). And you are absolutely correct that the issue was indeed the form action attribute JRoute::_('index.php') was the cause as the action was simply 'appending' to the menu item (hence /?genre=fiction in root and /used-books?genre=fiction when the module was submitted from used-books link). 

I simply added a module param to select the menu item ID and then used it like this on the form and this did the trick.

`JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=' . $itemid . '&view=search')`

Comment: Sweeeeet, glad you got it working!